# How to setup specific tax rule for a specific website in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, tax, multi-website, tax-rule

As per We required to set up a specific tax rule for a specific website.
to set website-specific tax rules.

Please give me a suggestion or link or any programmatic script so I can
do this ASAP

Thank you,

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Fill the Tax Rule Information

- On the Admin Panel, Stores > Taxes > Tax Rules.
- In the upper-right corner, click on Add New Tax Rule.
- Under the Tax Rule Information section, set Name for the new rule.
- From the tax rate list, choose one of them to enable for the rule. However, for each the existing tax rate, you can edit it as the following:
- Tap the Edit icon on the row.
- Edit the tax rate information on the Tax Rate page, then click Save.

Also you can take reference from below url:

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-tax-rules-magento-2.html#step-2-configure-additional-settings

Comment: the question is asking for specific website